# PHP Rotate image file permanently

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I want a user to be able to permanently rotate an image file clockwise or counter clockwise. I have tried imagejpeg($rotate) but can't seem to make it work right.

```
            <form method="GET" action="rotate.php">
                Rotate:<input type="radio" name="rotate" value="clockwise">Clockwise
                <input type="radio" name="rotate" value="counterclockwise">Counter clockwise
                <input type="Submit" name="Submit1"/>
            </form>
```

I am trying to allow the user to be able to choose the radio button direction and click "Submit". Then the displayed image will update rotated to whichever direction they chose and stay that way permanently whenever it is used again. Any help or direction?

```
    <img src=\"uploads/$user/$folder/$image\"/></a>";
```

Comment: this `<img src=\"uploads/$user/$folder/$image\"/></a>";` doesnot make any sense with the code provided you ..please provide the more relevant information

Comment: How about reading the PHP manual ... [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php)

Comment: This looks like a php string, @Registered User.

Comment: I only put the img tag in there to show that the image was being displayed afterward in the html. I didn't mean to make it confusing..Just seeing if you could shed any furhter light on how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `imagerotate()` this will rotate image permanently.

```
<?php
// File and rotation
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$degrees = 180;

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Load
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Rotate
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);

// Output
imagejpeg($rotate);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php

Or you can use this using jquery

http://www.linein.org/examples/jquery_rotate/

Comment: By permanently I guess he meant to overwrite the old image with the rotated image. Which this code doesn't do. But it's a start :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate your picture *permanently*, HTML or CSS is not the way to go. You will need some server-side scripting to store the rotated picture.

You sould have a look at [GD library](http://php.net/manual/fr/ref.image.php). For this kind of image manipulation, I have been using [Imagine library](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine), which is a library based on GD.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else ever needs this. Here is a function that will replace the original with the rotated image:

```
    public function autoRatateImage($src, $exifCode = ''){

        if($exifCode == ''){
            $exif = exif_read_data($src);
        }else{
           $exif['Orientation'] = $exifCode; 
        }
        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
        if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
            switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
                case 3:
                    $image = imagerotate($source, 180, 0);
                    break;

                case 6:
                    $image = imagerotate($source, -90, 0);
                    break;

                case 8:
                    $image = imagerotate($source, 90, 0);
                    break;
            }
            if (file_exists($src)) {
                unlink($src);
            }
            imagejpeg($image, $src , 100);  
        } 

    }
```